# unable to schedule a task using taskschedule package in R

Tags: r

I am trying to use taskscheduleR to execute script daily like this:

```
library(taskscheduleR)
setwd("C:/perf_data/")
myscript <- system.file("extdata","dailyJob.R", package = "taskscheduleR")
```

but when try to see the output of myscript, it is empty:

```
 myscript
[1] ""
```

any ideas what I am missing here?

Comment: By default there is no 'dailyJob.R' script in taskscheduleR's extdata folder.  There is a 'helloworld.R' script - is that what you wanted?

Comment: `taskscheduler_create(rscript = "C:/perf_data/dailyJob.R", ...)` assuming that your script is located at C:/perf_data

Answer (score -1):

if you are trying to get an object by sourcing the script, you need to `source` the script:

```
source(system.file("extdata","dailyJob.R", package = "taskscheduleR"))
```

Depending on where you use the source function, you need to set `local` parameter to TRUE.

```
result<-source(system.file("extdata","dailyJob.R", package = "taskscheduleR"))$value
```

result would have your output. Its not clear what you are trying to do.